# An error with youtube-dl

Tags: youtube-dl

When I run youtube-dl and extract the audio it gives me the error:
`ERROR: audio conversion failed: Unknown encoder 'libmp3lame'`
Could this be because I have ffmpeg and lame installed? Do the two conflict with eachother somehow?

Comment: try xtreme video download manager for downloading videos

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure that you have the `libavcodec-extra-53` package for encoding to mp3 installed. To install libavcodec-extra-53 from the terminal run:

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-53
```

Libav codec library:
Libav is a complete, cross-platform solution to decode, encode, record, convert and stream audio and video.

- In Ubuntu 14.04 the Libav codec library (libavcodec-extra-53) has been updated to libavcodec-extra-54.
- In Ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04 the Libav codec library has been updated to libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56.
- In Ubuntu 16.10, 17.04, 17.10, and 18.04 Libav codec library has been updated to libavcodec-extra57.
- In Ubuntu 18.10, 19.04, 19.10, 20.04, 20.10, 21.04, 21.10 and 22.04 Libav codec library has been updated to libavcodec-extra58.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem but installing that package didn't work for me.  When I ran this command, the problem was solved:  `sudo aptitude install ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Answer (score 0):

**If you're getting this error running youtube-dl on a server**
check out this example for how I solved it for running python app on heroku:
https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/302#issuecomment-60146845

The steps were

1. make sure lame is installed (I used a buildpack) and
2. make sure `ffprobe` is installed

There are presumably other ways:
`--extract-audio` "requires ffmpeg or avconv and ffprobe or avprobe"
https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl#post-processing-options